# Play 2.0.4 Java with Guice plugin - Error at application startup

Tags: playframework-2.0, guice

We have guice set up as in the documentation and it seems to work fine but we get following error in the application log:

> [warn] application - maybe inject.modules config parameter is not set propery?
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: module.Dependencies
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
>       at com.typesafe.plugin.inject.InjectPlugin.createModules(InjectPlugin.java:88)
>       at com.typesafe.plugin.inject.InjectPlugin.availableModules(InjectPlugin.java:29)
>       at com.typesafe.plugin.inject.GuicePlugin.onStart(GuicePlugin.java:33)
>       at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:60)
>       at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:60)
>       at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:59)
>       at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:45)
>       at play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:60)
>       ...

Is that something to ignore? The inject.modules seems to be default value if nothing has been specified in application.conf for inject.modules.

Comment: How are you making the bindings ? (https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/blob/master/guice/sample/app/module/Dependencies.java)

Comment: Ah, there was a mistake with that. Fixed now.

Comment: I provided an answer for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide a class called `module.Dependencies` to make the bindings, for instance:

```
package module;

import com.google.inject.*;
import service.*;

public class Dependencies implements Module {

 public void configure(Binder binder) {
     binder.bind(Service.class).to(SomethingService.class);
  }  
}
```

Take a look [here](https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/blob/master/guice/sample/app/module/Dependencies.java).